# Is it possible to have dynamic object properties in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, while-loop

I want to add new properties to an object based on loop iterations, is this possible in .Net? The reason I want to do this is I am looping through rows in an excel spreadsheet and for every successfully read row I want to create a new dynamic object property. So when the loop is complete I can simply pass the object to a method and log all the records.

See below for code so far:

```
    protected void ReadData(string filePath, bool upload)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        #region upload
        if (upload == true) // CSV file upload chosen
        {

            using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filePath), true)) // Cache CSV file to memory
            {
                int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount; // Total number of fields per row
                string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders(); // Correct CSV headers stored in array 

                SortedList<int, string> errorList = new SortedList<int, string>(); // This list will contain error values
                ORCData data = new ORCData();

                bool errorFlag = false;
                int errorCount = 0;

                // Check if headers are correct first before reading data
                if (headers[0] != "first name" || headers[1] != "last name" || headers[2] != "job title" || headers[3] != "email address" || headers[4] != "telephone number" || headers[5] != "company" || headers[6] != "research manager" || headers[7] != "user card number")
                {
                    sb.Append("Headers are incorrect");
                }

                else
                {
                    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                        try
                        {
                            //Check csv obj data for valid values
                            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (i == 0 || i == 1) // FirstName and LastName
                                {
                                    if (Regex.IsMatch(csv[i].ToString(), "^[a-z]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) == false) //REGEX letters only min of 5 char max of 20
                                    {
                                        errorList.Add(errorCount, csv[i]);
                                        errorCount += 1;
                                        errorFlag = true;
                                        string text = csv[i].ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (errorFlag == true)
                            {
                                sb.Append("<b>" + "Number of Error: " + errorCount + "</b>");
                                sb.Append("<ul>");
                                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> key in errorList)
                                {
                                    sb.Append("<li>" + key.Value + "</li>");
                                }
                            }
                            else // All validation checks equaled to false. Create User
                            {

                                string message = ORCLdap.CreateUserAccount(rootLDAPPath, svcUsername, svcPassword, csv[0], csv[1], csv[2], csv[3], csv[4], csv[5], csv[7]);
                                // TODO: Add to object here
                                sb.Append(message);
                                //sb.Append("<b>New user data uploaded successfully</b>");
                            }

                        }// end of try



                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            sb.Append(ex.ToString());
                        }

                        finally
                        {
                            lblMessage.Text = sb.ToString();
                            sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
                            hdnRdoSelection.Value = "1";
                        }
                }
            }

        }
        #endregion
```

I have never tried to do this before so I am not sure how I would approach it but any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Might I suggest a simpler example? it is not clear where the bit is that you want to add dynamic properties. Frankly, a `for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) obj.SomeProp = value;` might show the intent more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add new properties to an object based on loop iterations, is this possible in .Net?

Sort of. You probably want to use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), treating it as an `IDictionary<string, object>` when you're adding the properties.

Having said that, if you're not going to try to use those properties *as properties* later, do you actually need them to be properties at all? Why not just use a `Dictionary<string, object>` to start with?

Comment: So if I was to use a collection<int, string> and for this collection object concatenate multiple strings with comma delimiter, would this be a good solution? I could parse the string part of my collection within my class which creates the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) for this. Simply assign the properties you want and it will assume those properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic settings= new ExpandoObject();
```